# I'm adding text to a word document and need to include subscripts

Tags: vb.net, office-interop

I've opened a word document using word interop, and added several paragraphs of text. These vary in length depending on a range of factors. Then I add a line of text that includes CR in subscript like this (Subscripts of the letters CR are not included in Unicode subscripts):

```
            Dim word As Word.Application = New Word.Application()
            Dim doc As Word.Document

            'more code inserting paragraphs here


            Dim Paratext as string

            Paratext = "Elastic Critical Buckling Load  N_CR=(π² (E/Yₘ )I)/(L_CR∙L² )"

            para0 = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
            para0.Range.Text = Paratext
            para0.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()
            para0.Range.Style = doc.Styles("Normal")

            Dim Rstart As Int16 = Paratext.IndexOf("CR")
            Dim Rend As Int16 = Paratext.IndexOf("=")

            ' this is wrong: I select the range in the document
            ' using the location in the paragraph.

            Dim SRange = doc.Range(Rstart, Rend)

            SRange.Select()

            Dim currentselection As Word.Selection = word.Selection
            currentselection.Font.Subscript = 1
```

Edit: I am selecting the wrong text.  I'm identifying the location of the letters CR in the paragraph I just added, and applying this to the document which already has several paragraphs added.  So two characters at index 35 and 36 of the document not the paragraph become subscript.
How can I get the index of the start of the paragraph I just added?

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: no error it just doesn't change the text

Comment: I've realised where I've gone wrong.  I've identified the location of "CR" in the paragraph, then applied the range to the whole document.  How do I select a range in the paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it:

```
Dim word As Word.Application = New Word.Application()
        Dim doc As Word.Document

        'more code inserting paragraphs here

        'locate the end of the document so far
        Dim DocEnd As Int16 = doc.Content.End - 1

        Dim Paratext as string

        Paratext = "Elastic Critical Buckling Load  N_CR=(π² (E/Yₘ )I)/(L_CR∙L² )"

        para0 = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
        para0.Range.Text = Paratext
        para0.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()
        para0.Range.Style = doc.Styles("Normal")

        Dim Rstart As Int16 = Paratext.IndexOf("CR")
        Dim Rend As Int16 = Paratext.IndexOf("=")


        Dim SRange = doc.Range(Rstart + DocEnd, Rend + DocEnd)

        SRange.Select()

        Dim currentselection As Word.Selection = word.Selection
        currentselection.Font.Subscript = 1
```